# Could load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

This is killing me. I have cleared out the offending packages, uninstalled the packages, reinstalled, attempted to add a `<PackageReference>`, tried targeting multiple frameworks with `<targetFrameworks>`... All of the things and I am still getting this error at runtime.

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library that is being consumed by a .NET Framework 4.8 project. The framework project does not reference any of the IdentityModel.Tokens/Jwt objects. I have manually copied the assembly from the packages location in to the bin folder of the offending project and it does not seem to change the result.

**Fusion Log**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (1/7/2021 @ 11:38:12 AM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  REDACTED\REDACTED\bin\Debug\REDACTED.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file: REDACTED
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = REDACTED.exe
Calling assembly : REDACTED.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: REDACTED\REDACTED\bin\Debug\REDACTED.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///REDACTED/REDACTED/bin/Debug/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: REDACTED\REDACTED\bin\Debug\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from REDACTED\REDACTED\bin\Debug\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting an additional set of eyes on it, it turns out that the root project file (we do things a little differently) that references the .NET Framework project requires a reference to the assembly that wasn't being loaded.

Don't know why, but maybe something to do with MVVM and using a root project as a wrapper/driver for the application.